# Example of set subtraction in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I'm taking a data structures course in Python, and a suggestion for a solution includes this code which I don't understand.

This is a sample of a dictionary:

```
vc_metro = {
    'Richmond-Brighouse': set(['Lansdowne']),
    'Lansdowne': set(['Richmond-Brighouse', 'Aberdeen'])
}
```

It is suggested that to remove some of the elements in the value, we use this code:

```
vc_metro['Lansdowne'] -= set(['Richmond-Brighouse'])
```

I have never seen such a structure, and using it in a basic situation such as:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
other_list = [1, 2]
my_list -= other_list
```

doesn't work. Where can I learn more about this recommended strategy?

Comment: So do you want to remove all `1`s ans `2`s from the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: I want to dynamically remove items, sometimes one, sometimes more.  There should never be doubles in the list, but in any case doubles are irrellevant.  If there were, I'd want them all removed.

Comment: I think you need to read about `set`, which is a fairly ubiquitous python builtin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't subtract lists, but you can subtract [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) objects meaningfully. [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are hashtables, somewhat similar to [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), which allow only one instance of an object.

The `-=` operator is equivalent to the [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) method, except that it is in-place. It removes all the elements that are present in both operands from the left one.

Your simple example with sets would look like this:

```
>>> my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> other_set = {1, 2}
>>> my_set -= other_set
>>> my_set
{3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Curly braces with commas but no colons are interpreted as a set object. So the direct constructor call

```
set(['Richmond-Brighouse'])
```

is equivalent to

```
{'Richmond-Brighouse'}
```

Notice that you can't do `set('Richmond-Brighouse')`: that would add all the individual characters of the string to the set, since strings are iterable.

The reason to use `-=`/`difference` instead of [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.remove) is that differencing only removes existing elements, and silently ignores others. The [`discard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.discard) method does this for a single element. Differencing allows removing multiple elements at once.

The original line `vc_metro['Lansdowne'] -= set(['Richmond-Brighouse'])` could be rewritten as

```
vc_metro['Lansdowne'].discard('Richmond-Brighouse')
```